# How do I combine information from multiple rows without getting duplicate values in my ms acess report?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a table (named: tblSales) with following fields in ms access:

```
SalesAgent
SalesMonth
ProductCategory
SalesAmount
```

I have information like this:

```
SalesMonth     SalesAgent  ProductCategory  SalesAmount
Jan               A1          W1              5,000
Jun               A1          W2              3,500
Oct               A2          W1              4,000
Oct               A3          W1              2,500
Nov               A3          W3              1,500
Dec               A1          W1                800
Dec               A1          W3              2,000
```

I want to create an access report that looks like this:

```
SalesMonth      SalesAgent   ProductCategory   SalesAmount
Jan              A1             W1               5,000
Jun              A1             W2               3,500
Oct              A2             W1               4,000
                 A3             W1               2,500
Nov              A3             W3               1,500
Dec              A1             W1                 800
                                W3               2,000
```

Comment: If you need `access report` then tag the post `MS-Access` Why excel?

Comment: do you want to edit the information within the same month, can you explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I want the report in such in a way that, if for instances, salesmonth is same, then the sales month should only be show in 1 row, for the next row which bears the previous sales month, it should be blank (see for October). If for instance, sales agent is same as the previous sales agent and the salesmonth is also same for the previous month, then salesagent would also be blank (see that for December)

Comment: In case of access report you can set `Hide Duplicates` to `Yes`.

Comment: If you do that, in instances where the information in the 1st column is equal but those in the 2nd column differ, it does not work well. so we need to actually find a way to check columns before hiding or not hiding.

Comment: Unfortunately, the criteria for determining whether data should hide is based on data in other records. This would not be easy to accomplish. In fact, so difficult it approaches impossible.

Comment: You can use groups in access report to achieve this - you need to group by month, then by sales agent, then by product category.  This will give you the data you want, as best as i can understand it from your question.

Comment: As @JennyW says this is basic Grouping in Access Reports - check the bottom of your report for options to group and sort - you can add a sum to your query if you want only one totaled row per agent